# Number of isosceles triangles in a regular heptagon

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If any three vertices are chosen from $7$ sided regular polygon (a heptagon), then find the probability that the chosen vertices form an isosceles triangle.

**My attempt:**

The total number of ways $\displaystyle n(S) = \binom{7}{3}$. The number of favorable cases $\displaystyle n(A) = 7$ (in which two sides are common with a heptagon).

How can I calculate other isosceles triangles?

Comment: You are undercounting the "favourable cases". You can draw $3$ isosceles triangles from each vertex of the heptagon, having the equal sides meet at that vertex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are seven vertices you can consider as the top of three possible isosceles triangles. For instance, if the vertices in circular order are called $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_7$, the triangles $\Delta X_1X_4X_7$, $\Delta X_2X_4X_6$ and $\Delta X_3X_4X_5$ are all isosceles triangles. As such, the probability that a chosen triangle is an isosceles one equals:

$$\frac{{7 \choose 1} {3 \choose 1}}{7 \choose 3} = \frac{21}{35} = \frac{3}{5}$$